# Float image at top of right column in multi-column layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this one and I am surprised that others have not asked the same question here or elsewhere.

Imagine that I have a two-column layout using:

```
columns:100px 2;
-webkit-columns:100px 2;
-moz-columns:100px 2;
```

These columns are fluid as the browser window is resized so my question is simply, how do I have an image fixed at the top of the right column?

Thanks.

EDIT:

With Flixer's suggestion below, I now have this as the code I am working with but unfortunately the result is the image appearing in the first column like an inline element. The ideal outcome is the image appearing in a fixed position in the second column with text wrapping around it.

```
<style>
.cols2 {
    columns:350px 2;
    -webkit-columns:350px 2;
    -moz-columns:350px 2;
}

.cols2 > *:nth-child(2n) img {
    position:fixed;
    padding: 5px;
 }
</style>


<div class="cols2">
<img src="myimg.png" width="300" height="200" />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique urna id nisi
consequat, vel faucibus eros sollicitudin. Nam interdum ipsum justo, sit amet dignissim 
tortor adipiscing cursus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in
faucibus.<br /><br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique urna id nisi
consequat, vel faucibus eros sollicitudin. Nam interdum ipsum justo, sit amet dignissim 
tortor adipiscing cursus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in
faucibus.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique urna id nisi
consequat, vel faucibus eros sollicitudin. Nam interdum ipsum justo, sit amet dignissim 
tortor adipiscing cursus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in
faucibus.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique urna id nisi
consequat, vel faucibus eros sollicitudin. Nam interdum ipsum justo, sit amet dignissim 
tortor adipiscing cursus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in
faucibus.<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique urna id nisi
consequat, vel faucibus eros sollicitudin. Nam interdum ipsum justo, sit amet dignissim 
tortor adipiscing cursus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in
faucibus.<br /><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
.cols2 {
    columns:80px 2;
    -webkit-columns:80px 2;
    -moz-columns:80px 2;
}
.cols2 > *:nth-child(2n) img {
    position:fixed;
}
```

This selects the image of every second child element within the .cols2 class-element (you can also write `.cols2 > *:nth-child(even) img` if it is more intuitive for you) and set it's position to fixed. Maybe you need to add a padding to `.cols2 > *:nth-child(2n)` to avoid layout collisions between image and text.